# Nav isn't at the top of the page?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have my nav at the top right of the page but it displays like 100px down from the top. I have no clue what's causing this, I tried altering the padding and margin of other things in the header but I cant solve it. Any help ?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CT Designs | Home</title>
    <!-- Stylesheets-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <!-- Fonts-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <div id="branding">
          <h1> CT Designs </h1>
        </div>
        <div id="menu">
          <svg height="40px" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="40px" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><path class="fill" d="M4,10h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2s-0.896-2-2-2H4C2.896,6,2,6.896,2,8S2.896,10,4,10z M28,14H4c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2  s0.896,2,2,2h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2S29.104,14,28,14z M28,22H4c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2s0.896,2,2,2h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2  S29.104,22,28,22z"/></svg>
        </div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About Me</li>
            <li>Projects</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>

  <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min" href="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  min-width: 80%;
  float: center;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("../resources/img/header.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

header .container #branding h1 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 70px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Roboto;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
  padding: 30px;
  border: solid 3px #fff;
}

header .container #menu {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
}

header .container #menu svg {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header .container #menu svg path.fill {
  fill: white;
}

header .container nav ul {
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

header .container ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: You can inspect your website with the developer tools of your browser. In most browsers you can open them using `Ctrl + Shift + i`. Then you can use the inspector to see what is causing the unwanted positioning.

Comment: @Schwesi I have done that and it has a big orange space over the nav and no matter how i try and alter the logo(which seems to be the source) I cant fix it

Comment: it's a block level element, use the `display` property to change that to inline or inline-block.

Comment: It seems to be the container class, the nav appears just below it which is confusing because in the html and css the nav is in the container

Comment: add a `<div style="clear:both"></div>` right below `</nav>`. See this link for more information: https://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set your `header .container nav ul` to float right, which is under your `div#menu`and that's where the space is coming: the space is caused by the `svg` element you have, which your 'hamburger' menu.

Here is one solution:

```
#menu {
  float: left;
}
header .container nav ul {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you so much :)